# apply top property to a div depending of number of items in a mysql database

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have a mysql database containing several items and I want to change top property of footer section via jquery depending of number of items in this mysql database.

this is server side part of newsletter.php

```
<?php
    //allow sessions to be passed so we can see if the user is logged in
    session_start();
    //connect to the database so we can check, edit, or insert data to our users table
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pwd') or die(mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db('newsletter', $con) or die(mysql_error());
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM papers";
    if(array_key_exists('rowcount', $_GET)) {
      $query = mysql_query("select count(*) as total FROM papers");
      $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
      $json = array('rowCount' => $result); // can add more data here
      return json_encode($json);
    }
?>
```

this is client side part of newsletter.php

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('newsletter.php?rowCount', function(data) {
        var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
        var ntop = jsonData.rowCount * 250;
        $('#footer').css('top', ntop);
    });
</script>
```

This is theorical solution but the browser send an error log 'jsonData is null'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to provide an endpoint JQuery can query through a $.post, $.get, $.ajax e.g.

```
$.getJSON('ajax.php?rowcount', function(data) {
  var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);

  var ntop = jsonData.rowCount * 250;
  $('#footer').css('top', ntop);
}
```

and a php script something like:

```
if(array_key_exists('rowcount', $_GET)) {
  $query = mysql_query("select count(*) as total from table_name");
  $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
  $json = array('rowCount' => $result); // can add more data here
  return json_encode($json);
}
```

Comment: OK. I will try as soon as possible and I will tell you if It's works

Comment: infensus, excuse me but I understand that but in which part of code should I call and parse the user/pwd data in mysql connection?

Comment: since the mysql stuff is server side you are free to connect to the database somewhere in that script, or better you make a seperate mysql script and include it and it would have methods to open and close your database, e.g. mysql->open() ..do query.. mysql->close(); return json;

Comment: Please. Do you think you could make some example of using mysql script in that case, please?

Comment: lots to choose from: https://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+mysql+wrapper+class

Comment: ajax.php ??? don't understand that callback. $.getJSON will be before of after php script ??

Comment: browser send this error: jsonData is null. I've change ajax.php with the name of the php document.

Answer (score 1):

```
function redraw(){
    var ntop = <?php echo $result['total'];?> * 250
    .....
}
```

is that what you want?